# How to passively sniff for TCP/HTTP get requests

Tags: python, http, tcp

I am looking to passively sniff HTTP GET requests (with an Rpi) to track the traffic of network devices.
So far I have the following code which I beleive sniffs all packets, filtering down to TCP ones that should contain HTTP requests:

```
#Packet sniffer in python
#For Linux - Sniffs all incoming and outgoing packets :)
#Silver Moon (m00n.silv3r@gmail.com)

import socket, sys
import sys
from threading import RLock
from struct import *

#Convert a string of 6 characters of ethernet address into a dash separated hex string
def eth_addr (a) :
  b = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(a[0]) , ord(a[1]) , ord(a[2]), ord(a[3]), ord(a[4]) , ord(a[5]))
  return b

#create a AF_PACKET type raw socket (thats basically packet level)
#define ETH_P_ALL    0x0003          /* Every packet (be careful!!!) */
try:
    s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

# receive a packet
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65565)

    #packet string from tuple
    packet = packet[0]

    #parse ethernet header
    eth_length = 14

    eth_header = packet[:eth_length]
    eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , eth_header)
    eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])
    source_mac = eth_addr(packet[6:12])
    print 'Destination MAC : ' + eth_addr(packet[0:6]) + ' Source MAC : ' + source_mac + ' Protocol : ' + str(eth_protocol)

    #Parse IP packets, IP Protocol number = 8
    if eth_protocol == 8 :
        #Parse IP header
        #take first 20 characters for the ip header
        ip_header = packet[eth_length:20+eth_length]

        #now unpack them :)
        iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

        version_ihl = iph[0]
        version = version_ihl >> 4
        ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

        iph_length = ihl * 4

        ttl = iph[5]
        protocol = iph[6]
        s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
        d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);

        #print 'Version : ' + str(version) + ' IP Header Length : ' + str(ihl) + ' TTL : ' + str(ttl) + ' Protocol : ' + str(protocol) + ' Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr)

        #TCP protocol
        if protocol == 6 :
            t = iph_length + eth_length
            tcp_header = packet[t:t+20]

            #now unpack them :)
            tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_header)

            source_port = tcph[0]
            dest_port = tcph[1]
            sequence = tcph[2]
            acknowledgement = tcph[3]
            doff_reserved = tcph[4]
            tcph_length = doff_reserved >> 4

            #print 'Source Port : ' + str(source_port) + ' Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Sequence Number : ' + str(sequence) + ' Acknowledgement : ' + str(acknowledgement) + ' TCP header length : ' + str(tcph_length)

            h_size = eth_length + iph_length + tcph_length * 4
            data_size = len(packet) - h_size

            #get data from the packet
            data = packet[h_size:]
            print 'Data: '
            print data
```

**This gives the following:**
(Run on Rpi on same subnet as PC browsing wikipedia)
[image: Sniffer output]

What would I need to do to decode the GET request string from this?
I.e. GET /tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ HTTP/1.1
Host: net.tutsplus.com...

Comment: there is [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#interactive-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity depends on how exact you want to be.

To be "perfect", you'll need to largely implement a TCP/IP stack.  You need to trace the 3-way handshake, handle (and ignore) retransmits, re-order packets, and merge the data payloads into a single stream.  You'll also have to be resilient, making reasonable guess in the case where your monitor misses a packet but it is received by the destination.

To be "good", you can make assumptions such as "a GET request will be in a single packet" (usually true) to avoid actual connection tracking but you still have to check for retransmitted packets.  In this case, "GET" will be the first three characters of a data packet and you can process from there until a \n\n or the end of that data packet.